# JQuery .ajax with Chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I get a jQuery AJAX response from localhost with

```
var ajaxsrc = $.ajax({type:"GET", url: "http://localhost:4540/get.aspx?i=<%=Request.QueryString["i"] %>" ,data:"",dataType: "html"}).responseText;
alert(ajaxsrc);
```

IE alerts the correct text but Chrome alerts empty strings. When I check with developer console I see that it connects to get.aspx and retrieves data, however cannot handle withing my code.

Any advices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [jQuery.ajax page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> Note that this usage - returning the result of the call into a variable - requires a synchronous (blocking) request! (async:false)

You need to have `async: false` in the settings object if you're going to do that kind of assignment with `.responseText`.

You're probably better off passing a `success` handler, though...

Comment: @kingjiv's answer is the "better off" way I mentioned. `async: false` will work, but needing it is often a symptom of overly linear thinking.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to block then use `async:false` as John posted.  Ideally though, you want to keep your AJAX asynchronous.  Something like this:

```
 $.ajax({type:"GET", 
         url: "http://localhost:4540/get.aspx?i=<%=Request.QueryString["i"] %>",                
         data:"",
         dataType: "html"
         success: function(data){
             alert(data);
         }
})
```